# Proj pipeline support in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, proj, postgis-raster, pipeline

I would like to use proj pipeline in PostGIS `ST_Transform` function.

My sample SRS is as follows:

> +proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=m +xy_out=us-ft +z_in=m +z_out=us-ft +step +inv +proj=affine +s31=0.0001114681107 +s32=-4.9243526e-06 +zoff=-204.82041421671258 +step +inv +proj=helmert +s=1.0 +theta=1260.81751160268 +x=-4937.257377537489 +y=11286.424894191185 +exact +convention=coordinate_frame +step +inv +proj=tmerc +a=20925604.474167 +axis=enu +k_0=1.0 +lat_0=40.564968481372 +lon_0=-112.06247332686 +rf=0.0033528106718306487 +x_0=1843937.2703695 +y_0=813356.04485812 +step +proj=cart +a=20925604.474167 +rf=0.0033528106718306487 +step +inv +proj=cart +a=6378137.0 +rf=298.2572229329577 +step +inv +proj=vgridshift +grids=g2012bu0.gtx +step +inv +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

I get the following error with `ST_Transform`:

```
ERROR: transform_geom: could not parse proj4 string '+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=m +xy_out=us-ft +z_in=m +z_out=us-ft +step +inv +proj=affine +s31=0.0001114681107 +s32=-4.9243526e-06 +zoff=-204.82041421671258 +step +inv +proj=helmert +s=1.0 +theta=1260.81751160268 +x=-4937.257377537489 +y=11286.424894191185 +exact +convention=coordinate_frame +step +inv +proj=tmerc +a=20925604.474167 +axis=enu +k_0=1.0 +lat_0=40.564968481372 +lon_0=-112.06247332686 +rf=0.0033528106718306487 +x_0=1843937.2703695 +y_0=813356.04485812 +step +proj=cart +a=20925604.474167 +rf=0.0033528106718306487 +step +inv +proj=cart +a=6378137.0 +rf=298.2572229329577 +step +inv +proj=vgridshift +grids=g2012bu0.gtx +step +inv +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1' squared eccentricity < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible yet to define a transformation with a Proj pipeline but it should be easy once the new function ST_TransformPipeline is ready. Follow the situation of this ticket https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5006 "ST_Transform: Support PROJ pipelines"

Answer is based on this PostGIS version:

> "POSTGIS="3.1.2 3.1.2" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120"
> GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.1" PROJ="7.1.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.2.3, released
> 2021/04/27 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12"
> LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" RASTER"

Comment: This is not completely true  as I'm able to execute the following query successfully.``SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_Point(97168.985189,92179.519409), '+proj=pipeline +step  +proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.859558783333 +lon_0=-111.39915361388 +k_0=1.0 +a=6378137.0000001015 +b=6356752.314200101 +x_0=874.9606299203758 +y_0=9787.440182870307 +towgs84=0.0,0.0,0.0 +units=m +no_defs +step  +proj=helmert +s=1 +theta=153191.535399821  +x=-6387.74752364828  +y=3167.65884817593 +exact +convention=coordinate_frame', 3857))``

Comment: I now have the challenge of how to achieve the same in WKT of the above proj pipeline as spatial_ref_sys table entry is not helping to transform the value

Comment: What versions do you have? Your query gives me `ERROR:  lwgeom_transform_from_str: Failed to transform CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_transform" statement 1`. I have `"POSTGIS="3.1.2 3.1.2" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.1" PROJ="7.1.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.2.3, released 2021/04/27 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" RASTER"`

Comment: PostgreSQL 11.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit, POSTGIS="2.5.2" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6" PROJ="Rel. 6.2.1, November 1st, 2019" GDAL="GDAL 2.3.1, released 2018/06/22" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12.99" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" RASTER

Comment: Odd. I copied your query as-is and it does not work for me even I seem to have newer versions.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. There is no enough documentation as well anywhere to check around. Thats the problem with OSGeo libraries

Comment: Try the mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/postgis-users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134881/discussion-between-arun-thatham-and-user30184).