# ST_TRANSFORM NAD27 to WGS84

Tags: postgis, proj

I've encountered an issue when transforming NAD27 coordinates to WGS84. The resulting WGS84 coordinates are off by quite a bit (10-12 feet in most cases) and it lead me to digging into why that is so. As a control, I converted the same point from NAD27 to WGS84 in ArcMap and hold that to be the truth.

```
select st_transform(st_setsrid(ST_POINT(-99.723991251, 35.954241741), 4267), 4326)

-99.7243815258533 35.95428699761289 -- ESRI Transformed (Control)
-99.7243847871355 35.954284680650595 -- Result of ST_TRANSFORM on CentOS7
```

Thinking it may be a difference in configuration or PROJ grids, I compared/contrasted a fresh install of Postgresql 13 and Postgis 3.2.2 on CentOS 7 with the official ​Postgis Docker image for the same versions.

**CentOS 7**

```
select postgis_full_version()

POSTGIS="3.2.2 628da50" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1" SFCGAL="1.3.7" PROJ="8.2.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.4.3, released 2022/04/22" LIBXML="2.9.7" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

**Docker**

```
select postgis_full_version() 

POSTGIS="3.2.2 628da50" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2" PROJ="7.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.15" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY
```

Now here is where I get confused. When I run the same ST_TRANSFORM as above on the Docker image, I get exactly what I need.

```
select st_transform(st_setsrid(ST_POINT(-99.723991251, 35.954241741), 4267), 4326)

-99.7243815258533 35.95428699761289 -- ESRI Transformed (Control)
-99.7243815258398 35.95428699761243 -- Official PostGIS Docker Image Transformed - proj 7.2.1

-99.7243847871355 35.954284680650595 -- Result of ST_TRANSFORM on CentOS7
```

I have done the following:

- Ensured proj-data grids are installed. Didn't help.
- Removed proj-data grids and copied grids from Docker to CentOS7 proj location. Still no luck.
- Altered spatial_ref_sys entries for 4267 and 4326 (NAD27 and WGS84, respectively) with no luck either.
- I tried installing proj 8.2.1 and 7.2.1 in different conda environments and running cs2cs and each result was the same and still different from the ESRI control point.

Can anyone help explain the differences or if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You are using different versions of Proj (PROJ="8.2.1" & PROJ="7.2.1") which is probably the issue

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't think it is. I tried installing proj 8.2.1 and 7.2.1 in different conda environments and running cs2cs and each result was the same and still different from the ESRI control point.

Comment: I suspect conda just points through to your underlying proj install - I'm not a conda user so I can't be sure

Comment: `projinfo -s epsg:4267 -t epsg:4326 --spatial-test intersects` lists 79 transformations for me. Maybe using just EPSG codes is not good but you should give the whole Proj pipeline so that PostGIS knows what to use.

Comment: By this answer https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-portal-questions/wgs84-to-nad27/td-p/629617 ESRI has also over 20 transformations for NAD27/WGS84, which one is the truth?

Comment: When transforming in ESRI, we use NAD27 to WGS84 (79) transformation (EPSG 15851). This transformation is listed in the projinfo call above. Does ST_TRANSFORM accept pipeline proj strings?

Comment: Here in a comment is an example that has worked for someone https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426042/proj-pipeline-support-in-postgis, I still have the same PostGIS version and the example query does not work for me.